# Minimum polynomial versus characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Suppose $A$ is an $8\times 8$ matrix with complex entries such that
$$
\begin{align*}
dim_{\mathbb{C}}(ker(A-2I))&=2\\
dim_{\mathbb{C}}(ker(A-2I)^2)&=3\\
dim_{\mathbb{C}}(ker(A-3I))&=3\\
dim_{\mathbb{C}}(ker(A-3I)^2)&=4\\
dim_{\mathbb{C}}(ker(A-3I)^3)&=5\\
\end{align*}
$$
I am asked to determine the characteristic polynomial and the minimal polynomial of $A$.

So it seems that since $A$ is $8\times 8$, then the vector space $A$ is acting on has dimension $8$. Further since $$dim_{\mathbb{C}}(ker(A-2I)^2)+dim_{\mathbb{C}}(ker(A-3I)^3)=8$$
we have $(x-2)^2(x-3)^3$ as the minimal polynomial of $A$. But I am unsure of how to tease out the characteristic polynomial from this information. It seems like I have some choices (as the characteristic polynomial must have the same roots as the minimal polynomial):
$$
\begin{align*}
(x-2)^2(x-3)^6\\
(x-2)^3(x-3)^5\\
(x-2)^4(x-3)^4\\
(x-2)^5(x-3)^3
\end{align*}
$$
How do I winnow the choices down with the information I am presented?

Comment: Have you learned about Jordan form / Jordan blocks?

Comment: Yes. The continuation of this problem asks that I compute both the rational canonical form and the Jordan canonical form. Once I know what the characteristic polynomial is, I can finish the computation. But I am missing something in the facts given to settle on one characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just knowing $\dim(\ker(A-2I)^2)=3$ and $\dim(\ker(A-3I)^3)=5$ shows that $2$ is an eigenvalue whose generalised eigenspace has dimension at least $3$, and that $3$ is an eigenvalue whose generalised eigenspace has dimension at least $5$. Since these subspaces always form a direct sum and the whole space has dimension $8$, we must conclude that those generalised eigenspaces are $\ker(A-2I)^2$ and $\ker(A-3I)^3$, and their sum is the whole space, so there are no other eigenvalues.

The characteristic polynomial is then $(X-2)^3(X-3)^5$, the exponents being the dimensions of the generalised eigenspaces.

For the minimal polynomial you know that $(X-2)^2(X-3)^3$ annihilates both generalised eigenspaces for $A$, and it is therefore an annihilating polynomial for $A$. The other dimensions cited show that no lower exponents will do, so $(X-2)^2(X-3)^3$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$.